# np.array() gives error: inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (31, 3) + inhomogeneous part

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I've run into an error that I've had some trouble fixing.

```
    finBlackSourceMoves = np.array(finBlackSourceMoves)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (31, 3) + inhomogeneous part.
```

I am attempting to change the following list into an numpy array:

```
[[11, 27, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [2, 38, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [38, 45, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [12, 20, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [5, 33, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [1, 11, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 
2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [33, 24, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [24, 17, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [8, 16, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [10, 18, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [6, 21, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [27, 36, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [21, 36, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [13, 21, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [15, 23, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [17, 10, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [10, 37, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [3, 12, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [4, 3, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [3, 12, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [7, 4, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [0, 4, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [12, 13, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [13, 4, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [4, 13, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [14, 22, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [21, 29, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [23, 31, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [13, 14, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [14, 21, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]], [22, 30, [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]]]
```

But it's throwing the error above claiming it has an inhomogeneous part or shape, but I am certain I am sending in consistently sized sub-arrays namely two integers and an 8x8 2d array of integers.

so [integer, integer, [8][8]integer].

What could be causing this?

Comment: Exactly what the error message says and what you describe is causing this. Not all elements in the list have the same shape.

Comment: Your sublist may be consistent, but they are still are 'inhomogeneous'.  You don't seem to appreciate what a multidimensional integer array looks like.  You could make an arrray from all the 'two integers', or all the 8x8, but you can't mix those.  Elaborate on what kind of array you want (shape, dtype)

Comment: I see, so if I were to flatten the 2d array into a 1d array of 64 items would that be a viable solution? I don't think the final shape is important for me, I just need the information as 3 separate elements in either integer or float dtype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy-n-paste and assign to `x`:

```
In [277]: len(x)
Out[277]: 31

In [278]: x[0]
Out[278]: 
[11,
 27,
 [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
  [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 9, 8]]]
```

Collecting the integers into an list, and array:

```
In [279]: data1=[i[:2] for i in x]    
In [281]: np.array(data1).shape
Out[281]: (31, 2)
```

Same for the 8x8 part:

```
In [283]: data2=[i[2] for i in x]    
In [284]: np.array(data2).shape
Out[284]: (31, 8, 8)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it :D. But I just figured it out thanks to your earlier comment, I did not fully understand what shape meant in this context, and that for the array to be 'Homogenous'  the elements needed to be of the same datatype and the same structure/shape, so I ended up just flattening the 8x8 and then just appending the first two integers and it worked.

Comment: The error message has been evolving for this kind of issue.  Originally `np.array` just punted, and made an `object` dtype array when it could make a normal array.  Then it started to warn that you needed to specify `object` dtype.  Now it's raising this 'ihomogeneous' error, which I agree is not vary helpful.  But there are many SO examples with that message, all saying that you are trying to make array from poorly formed data.